# #324 facebook error Api v.2.10cc

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have version of Facebook api v.2.10 from github PHP, but something changed in last period because i can't upload image on facebook anymore i get this error :

```
(#324) Requires upload file
```

And this is the code:

```
$data = [
    'message' => (string) $message,
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload((string)$photo_path)
];
$response = $fb->post('/'.$social_id.'/photos', (array)$data, (string)$accessToken);
```

And this is the path for image `$photo_path = 'wpub/facebook-imgs/56fc6b23b6cf277e782f0cde05822e784ae73f13.jpg';`

Comment: Most likely the path to your file is not correct ...

Comment: The path its correct 2 days ago worked great... nothing changed

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of what the fileToUpload method returns, and show it here?

Comment: Sure: `Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile Object
(
    [path:protected] => wpub/facebook-imgs/1fe8e1b76071b2fa93c6e2d5d2b521caafc17933.jpg
    [maxLength:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
    [offset:Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile:private] => -1
    [stream:protected] => Resource id #68
)`

Comment: I resolved, was my function problem and didn't call one IF condition :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, was my code problem because in function something overrided and not entered on if codition who call filetoupload. Thanks for helping :D